# Error 403, Access Denied

Tags: php, hosting

How can i fix this? i just hosted my site at byethost33.com for free, because this is my project and in need to host it.

I am getting problems with a page that says 403 access denied. how will i fix it? i dont have the error log since this is just free hosting. I don't know what to do because this is my first time hosting awebsite, i fixed database connections and stuff. but still it says 403 access denied.

and i have other problems, when logging in it wont load the page, just the header, because in my index.php i have a condition that would only change the header if logged in but will store the session. how can i fix this? thank you

Comment: the file permissions are wrong. you probably need to make them world readable (typically chmod 644 yourfile.php)

Answer (score -1):

Just try to examine your code for resolving URLs, since you may direct some visits to wrong places.